# How to initiate JavaScript Callback with MVC2 using RenderAction

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I am building a dashboard where I am iterating through a list of controls to render, and I need to initiate a general callback both after each control and after they are all completed.   I was curious what the best way to handle this is.  I can get the control specific callback fired off by placing `myUserControlCallback();` in the user control itself.  I'm just not sure how to run something like `allControlsRendered();`.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you tell us why do you need this callback?

Comment: The widgets being rendered all have a single function that needs to run once ALL of the controls have rendered.  They all have separate data sources and need to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many widgets there are you can put a counter inside `myUserControlCallback()` and count the invocations. When number of invocations reaches number of widgets you know that the current call is last and you can now call `allControlsRendered()`.